# Branches in Git vs Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

How do I return to a certain changeset (or tag) and branch out from that commit?
Once I branch out and committed changes won't affect the original branch?

```
 |
tag-----------------
 |                   \
branch-1          branch-2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
hg update branch-1
hg branch branch-2
```

edit

```
hg commit
```

Note that this is named branches and there are other ways to branch in Mercurial.